# Run different Office Scripts functions from same script depending on button clicked

Tags: typescript, office365, office-scripts

Say you have an Excel file containing two buttons, named `populate-current` and `populate-all`. Both buttons trigger the same Office Script, which contains something like the following:

```
function populateByRowIndex(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, rowIndex: number): void {
    // populate values for row
}

function getAllRowIndexesToPopulate(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook): number[] {
    // get row indexes
}

function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    const IS_POPULATE_ALL_BUTTON = ???

    if (IS_POPULATE_ALL_BUTTON) {
        for (const rowIndex of getAllRowIndexesToPopulate(workbook)) {
            populateByRowIndex(workbook, rowIndex)
        }
    } else {
        populateByRowIdx(workbook, workbook.getActiveCell().getRowIndex())
    }
}
```

What should `IS_POPULATE_ALL_BUTTON` be in order to make the desired function run depending on which button was clicked?

Alternatively: is it possible to reuse the logic from one script in another script by some other means, other than copy-pasting? `import { ... } from ...` gives "Cannot use import statement outside a module", and `const { ... } = require(...)` gives "Cannot find name 'require'." Basically, I just want a way to re-use the logic from `populateByRowIndex` without duplicating code — I don't mind if the result needs one or multiple script files.

Comment: AFAIK, , Office Scripts does not support importing external modules. I'm curious about why you're using two buttons to trigger the same script and then attempting to determine which button was clicked. There might be an alternative solution to achieve your goal without this extra complexity.

Comment: @taller triggering the same script from 2 buttons is an attempted workaround to the problem of not being able to import external modules. I don't want to duplicate `populateByRowIndex` in 2 separate files and then have to manually update it in 2 separate places every time the logic changes. I guess I could write using ESM and then use a bundler to inline the imports, but seems like overkill for something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [script parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/develop/user-input) and avoid the different buttons. That way, when someone uses the script, they'll get to input the row to update (or the binary option of all or the current row, as in your scenario).

Here's an example that lets the user pick between your two options. It uses a union of string literals to give the user two choices.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, populationSetting: "PopulateAll" | "PopulateCurrentRow") {
  if (populationSetting == "PopulateAll" ) {
    // get row indexes
  } else if (populationSetting == "PopulateCurrentRow") {
    // populate values for row
  }
}
```

And here's what the user will see when they run the script.

[image: The pop-up with script parameters showing the options PopulateAll and PopulateCurrentRow]